# ASP.net MVC regexp validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a model with a number of validation rules, all of which are working fine with the exception of one designed to validate a postcode.  The rule / property is defined as follows:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Postcode is required")]
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage="Postcode must be under 20 characters")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]?[ ]?[0-9][A-Za-z-[CIKMOVcikmov]]{2}", ErrorMessage="Postcode is not valid")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
```

Every time the postcode fails the RegEx validation, even though using the same RegEx in an online tester (e.g. http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) passes.  a couple of examples of UK postcodes which should pass are IP4 4DL and bn35fb

Comment: Is this valid?  [A-Za-z-[CIKMOVcikmov]]  Any alpha character, a dash, or any specific alpha?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom has a couple of regexes you can use, and which make it appear that your regex actually isn't accurate.  For example, it looks like the part I pulled out above should actually be something like:  [ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z] - the nested selector is actually supposed to indicate letters that are *not* allowed, but the way the expression is written they are still allowed.

Comment: The regex is taken from a document issued by the UK government (with lower case thrown in) so I'm hoping it should be correct - http://interim.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/govtalk/schemasstandards/e-gif/datastandards/address/postcode.aspx

Comment: I don't see a regex in that document.  If you want to *exclude* certain letters, you use a caret (^), not a minus (-), and it goes inside the square brackets.  However, that won't work in this case because of the rest of the expression around it.

Comment: If you click through to the schema it is there: http://interim.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/media/291370/bs7666-v2-0-xsd-PostCodeType.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes:

- You have not provided lower-case options for the R in the [0-9R] group or for the final [0-9A-Z] character before the space.  Unless you're using an Ignore Case option, those will only match upper case items.  And if you're using Ignore Case, then all of the other lower-case ranges are unnecessary.
- The brackets around the space are optional.  The ? operator matches the previous character, so the brackets would only be necessary if you had more than one character that might be in the set.
- The syntax that I questioned above is not standard.  I've been using regular expressions for 10 years, and I've never seen anything like this.  It "works", depending on your parser, but isn't even documented in the .NET parser where it works.  Note that it fails completely - it doesn't even parse the regular expression correctly, much less find any matches - in Javascript.  The *best* way to do this, which should be supported across the board, is to use [ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z] instead.  There's a Javascript regex tester at [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/), and I verified that your expression fails there but with this simple change it succeeds.
- Related to the previous, you haven't indicated where the validation actually occurs.  If you're using a client-side validator, it's actually running it in Javascript, not .NET.  That could definitely explain why it's failing on this expression.

TL;DR: Try replacing the final character pattern and see if it starts working.

Comment: Ah - I hadn't factored in the fact it was executing in Javascript.  changing the expression as per your suggestions has fixed it - I'm now using [A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've run this test

```
 var attr = new RegularExpressionAttribute(@"[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]?[ ]?[0-9][A-Za-z-[CIKMOVcikmov]]{2}");
 Assert.IsTrue(attr.IsValid("IP4 4DL"));
```

and it seems to work fine.

My only suggestion is to check that there's no whitespace either side of the incoming postcode.